# InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement - Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I got this error on my wordpress site in console: 
InvalidValueError: not an instance of HTMLInputElement
_.Ib @ js?key=apikey&libraries=places&mode=driving&ver=4.9.4:38

I saw some topics with this problem but i didn't find a solve because the problem is caused by the booking theme plugin (i think) and the link error comes from maps.googleapis.com ....

I don't know where to search to fix it, I searched on google a lot of thinks but nothing usefull, thank you.

Comment: look for a place to put a google map api key

Comment: i already did this, i use a valid api key